# Getting an error trying to connect to Amazon RDS with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and Postgresql. I am trying to connect a AWS RDS db in which I have setup a PostGresql database.

```
psql -h <name_of_my_instance>.ctmkmqls5kgp.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
psql: could not translate host name <name_of_my_instance>.ctmkmqls5kgp.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I have edited the command and the error message that I got.  would be replaced by the actual name of my instance.

Can someone please help me with this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with the IP address? If you can provide your host name format it will be help others to answer your question.

Comment: Did you literally use `<host_name>` instead of using the DNS name provided by RDS?

Comment: No Mark, I used the DNS name.. Just replaces it with <host_name> for this question..!!

Comment: Did you provide `--publicy-accessible` while creating the instance? Can you update the post with the command used to create the instance!

Comment: Hi Frank, yeah.. I provided publicy-accessible in my security group. As for the manner in which I created the RDS instance, I used the web console and not the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-p` option to specify your port number. `-h` option is only to specify your host.

Try this way :

```
psql -p 5432 -h <name_of_my_instance>.ctmkmqls5kgp.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U <your user name>
```